# What does this 'key' => __( 'Student Name', 'wet' ) mean in PHP array?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was reading this https://www.webetutorial.com/question/add-custom-cart-item-data-in-woocommerce/ and they use a lot of `__( 'Student Name', 'wet' )` in defining keys in arrays. Like below. What does it mean?

```
 $item_data[] = array(
        'key'     => __( 'Student Name', 'wet' ),
        'value'   => wc_clean( $cart_item['student-name'] ),
        'display' => '',
    );

     $item_data[] = array(
        'key'     => __( 'Gender', 'wet' ),
        'value'   => wc_clean( $cart_item['gender'] ),
        'display' => '',
    );

     $item_data[] = array(
        'key'     => __( 'Kid Size', 'wet' ),
        'value'   => wc_clean( $cart_item['kid-size'] ),
        'display' => '',
    );
```

Comment: It allows you to replace that text programmatically using a plugin (for translation or other reasons): https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/

Answer (score 1):

[`__` is a function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) that:

> Retrieve the translation of $text.
>  If there is no translation, or the text domain isn’t loaded, the original text is returned.

```
function __( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
    return translate( $text, $domain );
}
```

For more info follow the [documentation here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions).